# C prime number bug

Tags: c, algorithm, debugging, testing

I want to find if a number is a prime number or not using the square root method. My number is working fine for different numbers when I test it but I know there is a bug that I can not find. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int n)
{
    int i,root;

    if(n == 2){
        return 1;
    }
    if(n % 2 == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    root = sqrt(n);

    for(i = 3; i <= root; i = i + 2){
        if(n % i == 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n,m;

    while (1){
        printf("Please enter a number(enter 0 to exit):");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n == 0){
            break;
        }
        if(1 == is_prime(n)){
            printf("%d is a prime number.\n", n);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", n);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is a bug?

Comment: I am writing the program from a book and it tells there is a bug but I can't find it.

Comment: Instead of trying with user input, write a loop and try your function with every prime from http://oeis.org/A000040 and every non-prime from http://oeis.org/A018252

Comment: I see two bugs a) missing library header `stdio.h` b) failure on corner case `1` which it reports as prime, but [1 is not prime](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html).

Comment: Starting with `if (n < 2) { return 0; }` cuts out a lot of non-primes.  Adding something to `root` avoids rounding errors, say add 0.5 to be sure: `root = sqrt(n) + 0.5;

Comment: Thanks. I believe that is the one I am looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a bug that I can not find

**Beware the subtleties of floating point math**

`root = sqrt(n);` can result in a `root` that is one less than expected due to imprecision/rounding.  Example: Consider `sqrt(49)` may return 6.999999999999999... making `root = 6`. The loop stops before testing with 7 and returns `prime(49)` incorrectly as true.

Instead iterate until the quotient is too large.  This becomes true when `i` is about the square root of `n`.

```
// for(i = 3; i <= root; i = i + 2){
for(i = 3; i <= n/i; i = i + 2){
```

Avoid the below as `i*i` may overflow for primes near `INT_MAX`.

```
for(i = 3; i*i <= n; i = i + 2){  // Potential overflow
```

`n/i` is often a "freebie" when near `n%i` as good compilers emit common efficient code.

Alternatively, round up the square root calculation, if one is compelled to use `sqrt()`.  With other types like `long long n`, this may be insufficient.  Best to use integer math for an integer problem.

```
root = ceil(sqrt(n));
```

**Corner bug**:

Code returns true for `is_prime(1)`. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922781/c-prime-number-bug/63922867#comment113036013_63922781) Suggest returning in the end:

```
// return 1;
return n >= 2;
```

Code dies with `is_prime(negative_odd)` as `sqrt(negative_odd)` is attempted.  Suggest `sqrt()`-less solution.

Other problems may exist.

Comment: Rounding down is okay in this case, actually, because the OP compared `i` to `sqrt(n)` using `<=` and not `<`. So this answer solves a problem that doesn't exist, and doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Not me, but I was admonished by one user who told me that such a `sqrt` function would be "defective".

Comment: @interjay No. If `n` is a composite number, then there exist two integers `a,b` such that `a * b == n`, and if `a <= b`, then necessarily `a <= floor(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: @Stef `sqrt(prime_n_times_prime_n)` may return n-1.99999999999999 and that truncates to an `int` as `n-1`.  Thus the need for `ceil()` before converting to `int`. `a <= sqrt(n)` thus iterates one less than needed.  `a <= floor(sqrt(n))` fails too.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "n-1.99999999999999" but I insist, there is no need for `ceil`.

Comment: @Stef Consider sqrt(49) may return 6.9999999999999 making `root = 6`.  The loop stops before testing with  7 and return `prime(49)` incorrectly as true.

Comment: Ooooooooooooooooooh okay I see.

Comment: @chux: My understanding is that sqrt is supposed to round correctly, assuming that the C library is IEC 60559 compliant and that the rounding direction is unaltered from the default. (Those assumptions may be overly optimistic, of course.)

Comment: @rici Agree given that assumption, yet C   does not require adherence to 60559.  In my experience, many implementations are only _nearly_ 60559 compliant as  getting 100% compliance is _hard_. Note: in the case of `sqrt(some_64-bit_int)` we have the problem of rounding the argument, leading to more edge cases.  I suppose we could use `r = (int) sqrt(n)` as a first approximation and then use `root = max( r, n / r) + 1` for CYA code.  A potential few extra iterations poses no harm.  Or just code up `isqrt()`.

Comment: @chux:  The `i <= n/i` version you suggest in the answer is probably the best for this problem, anyway. As you say, it's almost free with a good compiler.